# jQuery - How to get browser window to scroll horizontal when div is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have picture of an arrow in a div. This div is fixed in the bottom right corner of very wide page.

How can I use jQuery to scroll the window right 600px each time the div is clicked? (And is it possible to detect when the page can no longer scroll right, and hide the arrow?)

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the jquery method scrollLeft

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scrollLeft((Number($(window).scrollLeft())+600)+'px');
});
```

Something like that :)

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
var distance = 600;
$("div").click(function() {
    $("html:not(:animated), body:not(:animated)").animate(
        {scrollLeft: "+="+distance}, 400
    );
});
```

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/juXLu/2/

[edit]
And here's detecting if you're at the end of the document http://jsfiddle.net/lukemartin/juXLu/5/

```
var distance = 600,
    docWidth = $(document).width(),
    scrollPos;

// click handler
$("div").click(function() {

    // animate 
    $("html:not(:animated), body:not(:animated)").animate(
        // amount to scroll
        {scrollLeft: "+=" + distance},
        // scroll speed (ms)
        400,
        // callback function
        function(){
            // check our scroll position
            scrollPos = $(window).width() + $(window).scrollLeft(); 
            // if it equals the doc width, we're at the end
            if(docWidth === scrollPos) {
                $("div").text("End of the line");
            }
        }
    );    

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could user the Scrollto plugin,

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo

It is really easy to use, just use the documentation. Then you could create a placeholder to determine whether or not its to the end of the page. Just stick the placeholder at the very end, and calculate the distance.

Comment: ill try to come up with some code to help you out, but i am a little busy right now.