# Scroll Browser Window with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to scroll the browser window in response to certain user actions.

I found out about [`scrollLeft` in a stackoverflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061241/jquery-how-to-get-browser-window-to-scroll-horizontal-when-div-is-clicked). From there, I was able to find `scrollTop` and ended up with the following:

```
$(window).scrollTop((Number($(window).scrollTop())+100)+'px');
```

This does in fact scroll, but to the top of the page. No matter what value I replace 100 with (I even tried negative numbers), it always just jumps to the top of the page. (Note: `$(window).scrollTop()` is returning 0.)

Can someone give me some tips to what I might be missing?

Comment: If you are using an anchor link, you should prevent the default action of the event. `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: It's in response to the mouse moving over an element. (It's not implemented yet but it will be a timer handler when I'm done.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scrollTop` just takes a number, rather than a `px` value.

```
$(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop()+100);
```

That should be enough.

Comment: Yes! That fixed it. "px" was used in the stackoverflow I referenced in my question where I found out about `scrollleft`.

Answer (score 1):

YOu don't need `Number` cause `scrollTop` returns a number

`scrollTop` will perform if there's some `scrollHeight` available that is higher than the  element's height, and it's always a positive number.

and it should look like:

```
$(window).scrollTop( $(window).scrollTop()+100 );
```

you don't need the `'px'`

Comment: What did you do to try it offline. Just download everything to your local computer?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out. For this, it looks like the 'px' was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

No `px` required...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scrollTop(($(window).scrollTop()+600));
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tGxJV/)

Comment: `Number` is not needed at all, scrollTop returns an integer